# use grep to capture regex

Tags: regex, grep

I have trouble capturing text like the following in input:

```
"xy$"
```

I did

```
grep -eo '([a-zA-Z]+)$'
grep -eo '([a-zA-Z]+)\$'
grep -eo '([a-zA-Z]+)\\$'
```

here the $ represents the literal $ not end of line.
what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `$`, so it becomes a literal

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the $. `grep -eo '([a-ZA-Z+)\$`

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on *extended* regexes with the `-E` option:

```
grep -E '([a-ZA-Z]+)\$'
```